# System becomes unusable due to hard disk 100% usage with AVG, WhatsApp, Chrome, and System at various times

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, google-chrome, avg-antivirus, whatsapp

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 2017 model with Windows 10 OS and SATA hard disk, with 12 GB RAM and i5 processor.

Last many months, I have been facing 100% disk usage at various times, and it is different applications at different times.

Sometimes it is AVG which causes 100% disk usage, sometimes it is Google Chrome, sometimes it is WhatsApp desktop version, and sometimes it is just the System process.

I have searched many articles and tried many steps:

1. Windows 10 is updated, as it has auto-updates
2. I have disabled SuperFetch
3. I have scanned the system for viruses
4. Turned off Windows search indexing
5. Disabled all unnecessary startup applications
6. Deleted temporary files and folders.

But nothing seems to provide a permanent solution.

How can I provide you more information, as the problem does not happen ALL the time, but happens very very frequently. If you want me to upload any logs from any diagnostic utilities, please let me know.

Request moderators not to remove this question as duplicate. Yes it is duplicate but none of the other provided solutions is working.

Let me know what additional details you need.

EDIT 1:

Below is a screenshot of hard disk status from the CrystalDiskInfo utility. **It shows the Health Status as Good.**

[image: Hard Disk Status]

EDIT 2:

Below is the result of running the Check button from the C and D drives properties window:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not a Windows guy but this sounds like a swap space problem. Your RAM-hogging apps like Chrome (and Chromium-based Electron apps like WhatsApp Desktop probably is) are probably using so much virtual memory that your VM swapfiles are taking your free space. The Unixy solution would be to make a dedicated swap partition so that VM swapfiles can't eat up your free space on your other filesystem(s).

Comment: I have posted SMART values of HDD above. It shows the Health Status as Good

Comment: I'd recommend buying an SSD

Comment: Is there any issue with my HDD as per the screenshot above